# how to implement a recursive deletion in ruby on rails ?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making an app in ruby on rails, similar to `Reddit`, along the project I decided to use recursion on the `Comment` model using a `polymorphic association`.

Recursive deletion Article <- Comment <- Comment and so on

The problem is that when I delete the Article, which comments depends and using `:delete_all` (or `:destroy`, already tried that) on the `has_many` association, it will only delete the first level of comments.
The same way happens to the `Comments`, only the first level of replies gets deleted, and I really dont want orphan comments out there.

The question is, how can I implement a recursive deletion in this context?

**models/article.rb:**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable , :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**models/comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable , :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**articles_controller.rb:**

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @article.comments.destroy
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
end
```

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_commentable
                    .
                    .
                    .
    def create
      @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)

      if @comment.save
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your comment was successfully posted!'
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Your comment wasn't posted!"
      end
    end

    private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end

    def find_commentable
      @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
      @commentable = Article.find_by_id(params[:article_id]) if params[:article_id]
    end
end
```

**views/articles/show.html.erb**

```
.
.
.
<ul>
  <%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @article.comments) %>
</ul>
```

**views/comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= comment.body %> -
  <small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by <%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %></small>

  <%= form_for [comment, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id , :value => current_user.id) %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a Reply", required: true %><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Reply"  %>
      <% end %>
  <ul>
      <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments %>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are deleting the article or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:destroy` instead of `:delete_all` in both Comment and Article for the cascading to work properly as delete [does not trigger callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all).

Also note `@comments = @article.comments.destroy` will not do anything here (you have a `CollectionProxy` so it will [function like this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/destroy)) and you should be using `destroy_all` instead. This alone will not properly solve your recursive deletion problem, though, and will only delete comments of the top level of comments, and stop there. In fact, you don't need this line at all if you use `:destroy`.